# How can I get first column in oracle table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get first column in a oracle table for my select query
i.e. SELECT FIRST_COLUMN from TABLE. How can I do this? I do not have access to SYS tables i.e  no access to tables like user_tab_columns. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: In what context are you trying to achieve this? Straight SQ, PL/SQL or 3GL?

Comment: Not sure i understand what your are trying to archive here. if you are working in an sql tool, just do a 'select * from table' and choose the one you like.

Comment: Also, you should never rely on the "order" of a column ... it could change over time. The only good way is to request a column by its name.

Comment: The real solution here is to get access to the data dictionary views by talking to your DBA. If they are making your life difficult then they aren't doing their job properly. Is there ever a good reason not to provide access to these views?

Comment: Just like rows in a relational database have no inherent order, columns do not have an order as well. If your application logic requires the knowledge of what is the "first" column you should really rethink your design!

Comment: The name of the table is dynamic and I want to genrate a report with data having key field values.

Answer (score 3):

You ALWAYS have access to USER_TAB_COLUMNS.

Too much stuff breaks if the DBA tries to revoke it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have very limited access. If your accounts has access to DBMS_SQL you could try the following:

```
declare
lv_stat VARCHAR2(300) := 'SELECT * FROM tablename';
lv_cid integer;
lv_tab DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
lv_cnt int;
begin
  lv_cid := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(lv_cid,lv_stat,DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(lv_cid,lv_cnt,lv_tab);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First Column is '||lv_tab(1).col_name);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(lv_cid);
  EXCEPTION
  when others then
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(lv_cid);
end;
```

This could be wrapped into a PL/SQL function. Probably simpler to talk to your DBAs